# MonoTouch - OpenGL panel / split screen?

Tags: ipad, opengl-es, xamarin.ios

I need to present an OpenGL "panel" on the same screen as some controls, web/text content, etc. Any suggestions? Ideally I'd have an OpenGL control that could be dropped onto a form in Interface Builder and manipulated in the same way that buttons, etc. can.

I suppose a good OpenGL UI toolbox that provided standard controls like buttons, gesture control, etc. would also work.

The best analogy I can think of at the moment would be presenting 3D content on the top 1/3rd of the iPad screen, and related text and text-related navigation controls on the bottom, like they've done with some of the textbooks in the Apple TV commercials.

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763577/programmatically-defined-view-in-interface-builder), but am not really clear on the the meaning of the answer. (This is my first non-"Hello World" iOS app, so some of the terminology is unfamiliar.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `iPhoneOSGameView` to render any 3D content with OpenGL.

Here is an example of using it: https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/GLPaint-GameView/PaintingView.cs

I would think you should be able to place one of these view in a `UISplitViewController` on iPad, or just on 1/3 of the screen.  This is that split screen control you see in the mail app, for example.

Also, to use a class from Interface Builder all you need is:

```
[Register("MyClass")]
class MyClass { public MyClass(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { } }
```

So you have to register it, and include the IntPtr constructor.

Good luck, I haven't found an example of *exactly* what you're trying to do.

Comment: This didn't *exactly* solve my problem, but it got me going in the right direction. Thanks.